# Is there any problem using Euclidean Distance for a data set that includes a lot of values between 0 and 1?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, unsupervised-learning, preprocessing

I have a data set which includes 3 types of financial data (P/E, ROA, EPS growth) for each stock in a list of stocks. My goal is to use K-Medoids to cluster these stocks into groups based on this data.

I standardized each data point so it is represented as a standard deviation of the group of financial data it is apart of. However, most of my data is now between 0 and 1 and I was going to use Euclidean distance to sort the stocks.

Would there be any problem using Euclidean distance in this problem since the square root of a fraction makes the fraction larger?